# Output crash log to txt file

Tags: python, file-io, crash-reports

I'm using a subprocess to run another python file which tends to crash every now and then. I want to log the data from the (PyCharm) output and save it to a text file so that I can later figure out what the problem was. For example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

This would be the output after the subprocess crashed. I want to save this to a file, then restart the subprocess. It looks somewhat like this:

```
sub = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,...])

if sub.poll() is None:

    os.system("screencapture -x crash.png")
    file = open('log.txt', 'w')

    #file.write() the output

    start_process() #restarts the subprocess
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want

```
with open('log_file', 'w') as f:
    sub = subprocess.Popen(..., subprocess.STDOUT=f)
    retval = sub.wait()
    if retval != 0:
        start_process()
```